# Joomla 2.5 - Disable www.[websitename].com/?format=feed&type=rss

Tags: joomla

I have been searching forever trying to find a way to disable the feed link (ie: www.[websitename].com/?format=feed&type=rss).

Is there a way to disable this link? I have some bad google indexes of these and I want to return 404 not found when google tries to index them again.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the `libraries/joomla/document/feed/feed.php` file.

Find `__construct`  method of `JFeedDocument` class in the file and change it to look like this:

```php
function __construct($options = array()) {
  JError::raiseError(404, JText::_('Resource Not Found'));
}
```

But, in this case, you won't have "feed" support at all.

Comment: Not having feed support isnt an issue. I tried your suggestion but it caused a lot of error, not the traditional 404 not found.

Comment: Could you provide me with error details? I tried it with 1.5 not 2.5.

Comment: Do you want to disable access to feed link or disable feed creation?

Comment: I want to disable access to that link. I have a google index of www.[websitename].com/?format=feed&type=rss and I want to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is out there looking for this, what worked for me was setting 404 Not Found headers in the JDocumentFeed constructor:

```
function __construct($options = array()) {
    if (!headers_sent()) {
        header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
        //I guess you could include here a file to show the 404 page
    }
    exit();
}
```

The call for `JError::raiseError(404, JText::_('Resource Not Found'));` gave me a backtrace of the error.